# Каким образом генерируется код авторизации на чеке при оплате пластиковой картой?

Tags: случайные-числа, ecommerce

Каким образом генерируется код авторизации на чеке при оплате пластиковой картой?

Answer (score 1):

Его генерирует и присылает в ответ на проведение транзакции тот банк, который выдал карту. Обычно в формате nnnnnnABC, где

- A - результат проверки адреса через AVS (Yes/No/X)
- B - результат проверки ZIP через AVS  (Yes/No/X)
- C - результат проверки CVV2 (Yes/No/X)

Для российских карт результат скорее всего будет вида 123456XXY. Для оффлайновых платежей - просто 6 цифр.

Comment: Интересно именно как эти 6 цифр генерироваться?